# What would be the most efficient way to write a query in oracle sql developer to retrieve the number of devices, 90K+ record table

Tags: sql, oracle

for example:

I need to gather the number of devices "device_id" from the table "history_log" that have 15 or more '9000' "event_code" records; 15 or more '9001' "event_code" records; 3 or more '9002' "event_code" records; and 5 or more '9003' "event_code" records respectively, for the month of June (from June 1st to June 30th)

I am not able to combine a WHERE and HAVING clause and keep running into syntax errors.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Show us your query attempt. HAVING is probably the way to go.

Comment: No one can write sql against an unknown table.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, What I need is an output to also include all Device_IDs that have 15 or > '70000' Event_Code per day, 15 or > '70001' Event_Code per day, 3 or > '70002' Event_Code per day, and 5 or > '70003' Event_Code per day. Here is the code thus far: SELECT history_log.device_id, history_log.time, history_log.event_code FROM history_log WHERE history_log.event_code in ('70001','70002','70003','70004') AND history_log.time >= '01-JUN-21' AND history_log.time < '01-JUL-21' ORDER BY history_log.device_id, history_log.time DESC

Answer (score 1):

> I need to gather the number of devices "device_id" from the table "history_log" that have:
>
> - 15 or more '9000' "event_code" records;
> - 15 or more '9001' "event_code" records;
> - 3 or more '9002' "event_code" records; and
> - 5 or more '9003' "event_code" records respectively,
>
> for the month of June (from June 1st to June 30th)

You want to `GROUP BY device_id` within the date range and use conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause to count the individual `event_code` to ensure that your requisite amounts are met. Once you have found the matching `device_id` values then you can `COUNT` them all:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(device_id)
FROM   (
  SELECT device_id
  FROM   history_log
  WHERE  datetime >= DATE '2021-06-01'
  AND    datetime <  DATE '2021-07-01'
  GROUP BY device_id
  HAVING COUNT(CASE event_code WHEN 9000 THEN 1 END) >= 15
  AND    COUNT(CASE event_code WHEN 9001 THEN 1 END) >= 15 
  AND    COUNT(CASE event_code WHEN 9002 THEN 1 END) >=  3
  AND    COUNT(CASE event_code WHEN 9003 THEN 1 END) >=  5
)
```